# Displaying a location in TWebBrowser (Google Maps) without having to click a button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, delphi

How do I display the location in Google Maps without having to click the button in my Delphi/Windows app?  I'm trying to pass along an address when the user clicks on a "Show Location" button on a Customer form.  Currently, if the user clicks the "Show Location" button, the address is passed along, but the location is not displayed when the ViewMaps form opens.  But Once the ViewMaps (TWebBrowser) form is displayed, and shows the "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014" address in the Memo box, the user can click the "GoToAddressBtn" button and the location will display.

So how do I get the location to display on the Google Map without the user having to click the "GoToAddressBtn" button on the ViewMaps form?

```
   implementation

Uses ShredMain, ActiveX;

{$R *.dfm}

const
HTMLStr: AnsiString =
'<html> '+
'<head> '+
'<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> '+
//'<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />'+
'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script> '+
'<script type="text/javascript"> '+
''+
''+
'  var geocoder; '+
'  var map;  '+
//'  var address;  '+
'  var trafficLayer;'+
'  var bikeLayer;'+
'  var markersArray = [];'+
''+
''+
'  function initialize() { '+
'    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();'+
'    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714776,-74.019213); '+
//'    var address = "San Diego, CA";'+
'    var myOptions = { '+
'      zoom: 11, '+
'      center: latlng, '+
'      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP '+
'    }; '+
'    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); '+
'    trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();'+
'    bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();'+
'    map.set("streetViewControl", false);'+
'  } '+
''+
''+
'  function codeAddress(address) { '+
'    if (geocoder) {'+
'      geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) { '+
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          PutMarker(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), results[0].geometry.location.lat()+","+results[0].geometry.location.lng());'+
'        } else {'+
'          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);'+
'        }'+
'      });'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   map.setCenter(latlng);'+
'   PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Lat+","+Lang);'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'function ClearMarkers() {  '+
'  if (markersArray) {        '+
'    for (i in markersArray) {  '+
'      markersArray[i].setMap(null); '+
'    } '+
'  } '+
'}  '+
''+
'  function PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Msg) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'+
'      position: latlng, '+
'      map: map,'+
'      title: Msg+" ("+Lat+","+Lang+")"'+
'  });'+
' markersArray.push(marker); '+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function TrafficOn()   { trafficLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function TrafficOff()  { trafficLayer.setMap(null); }'+
''+''+
'  function BicyclingOn() { bikeLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function BicyclingOff(){ bikeLayer.setMap(null);}'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOn() { map.set("streetViewControl", true); }'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOff() { map.set("streetViewControl", false); }'+
''+
''+'</script> '+
'</head> '+
'<body onload="initialize()"> '+
'  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> '+
'</body> '+
'</html> ';

procedure TViewMaps.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Timer1.Enabled:= False; //Disable timer so it doesn't fire again
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
  if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
  begin
    aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
       aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLStr)^, Length(HTMLStr));
       //aStream.Write(HTMLStr[1], Length(HTMLStr));
       aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
       MemoAddress.Lines.Clear;
       MemoAddress.Lines.Add('1 Infinite Loop. Cupertino, CA 95014');
       address := MemoAddress.Lines.Text;
       address := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(address), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
       //HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(address)]), 'JavaScript');
       (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
    finally
       aStream.Free;
    end;
    HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
  end;
end;

procedure TViewMaps.GoToAddressBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   address := MemoAddress.Lines.Text;
   address := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(address), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
   HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(address)]), 'JavaScript');
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an address to the mapping form, you could pass it as a parameter of the form's constructor.

Create a private form varable named **fAddress**.

Then add the form's Public Constructor override passing the address:

```
  Public
    constructor create(AOwner: TComponent; AAddress: string); reintroduce;

implementation

constructor TForm1.create(AOwner: TComponent; AAddress: string);
begin
  inherited create(AOwner);
  fAddress := AAddress; // fAddress is now stored to form variable
end;
```

Your app also needs to make sure that the Google API is loaded first.  You don't need to use a TTimer, you just need to verify the TWebBrowser's READY_STATE to ensure that the Google API is fully loaded. Here I've moved your code to the form's OnShow event (tested).

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');

  if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
  begin
    aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLStr)^, Length(HTMLStr));
      aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
    finally
      aStream.Free;
    end;
    HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
  end;

  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do // wait for google
  begin
    sleep(0);
    application.processmessages;
  end;

  fAddress := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(fAddress), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
  HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(fAddress)]), 'JavaScript');
end;
```

To implement and display an address using your mapping form, you'd use the following from the calling form:

```
Form1 := TForm1.create(self, '15010 NE 36th St, Redmond, WA 98052');
try
  Form1.showmodal;
finally
  Form1.destroy;
end;
```

Comment: I added what you suggested, but I'm getting the error "A component named Panel1 already exists." when the calling form attempts to create the form from the line 'code' ViewMaps := ViewMaps.create(self, '15010 NE 36th St, Redmond, WA 98052');

Comment: In my example, form1 is your mapping form, are you sure you are attempting to create the mapping form? Try replacing self with nil

Comment: Yes, I changed form1 to ViewMaps which is my mapping form.  I tried nil, and I got the same error.  Here's my calling form code: 'procedure TMaintForm.ShowMapBitBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ViewMaps := ViewMaps.create(nil, '15010 NE 36th St, Redmond, WA 98052');
  try
    ViewMaps.showmodal;
  finally
    ViewMaps.destroy;
  end;
end;'

Comment: Sorry John, I'm not sure how to add code in the comments.

Comment: It should be Viewmaps := TViewmaps.create(nil, '15010 NE 36th St., Redmond WA 98052');

Comment: You might also want to make sure your project is not auto-creating the ViewMaps form, in Delphi, go to Projects, Options, Forms and make sure it's not in the auto-create forms list..